# How do storage upgrades work?

Tags: pokemon-go

Before I spend any "money" (poke-coins) on storage upgrades, I'd like to know how they work. I'm currently limited to 250 Pokemon and 350 items. Both capacity upgrades cost 200 poke coins.

How much does each upgrade increase my capacity? Is there only one upgrade, or can I continually upgrade my capacity for both Pokemon and items?

Comment: They both increase your space by 50 as it says in the description. I would assume you can buy multiples but I haven't bought any myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both storage upgrades increase your storage in that area by 50. This means you can either hold 50 more total Pokémon at a time or 50 more items, whatever those items might be(Lucky Eggs, Pokéballs, Incense, etc. all count for 1 storage apiece). You can continually upgrade both storage facets to your heart's content as long as you have the coins to do so.
Edit: As long as you don't want to have over 1,000 storage for either storage. 1,000 is the highest you can go.